# can't create a file larger than 2GB on 64 bit linux system with mmap/malloc/open etc

Tags: c, linux, memory, 64-bit, limits

OK I know questions like this have been asked in various forms before and I have read them all and tried everything that has been suggested but I still cannot create a file that is more than 2GB on a 64bit system using malloc, open, lseek, blah blah every trick under the sun.

Clearly I'm writing c here. I'm running Fedora 20, I'm actually trying to mmap the file but that is not where it fails, my original method was to use open(), then lseek to the position where the file should end which in this case is at 3GB, edit: and then write a byte at the file end position to actually create the file of that size, and then mmap the file. I cannot lseek to past 2GB. I cannot malloc more than 2GB either. ulimit -a etc all show unlimited, /etc/security/limits.conf shows nothing, ....

when I try to lseek past 2GB I get EINVAL for errno and the ret val of lseek is -1.edit: The size parameter to lseek is of type off_t which is defined as a long int (64bit signed), not size_t as I said previously.

edit: 
I've already tried defining _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE & _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64 and it made no difference.
I'm also compiling specifically for 64bit i.e. -m64

I'm lost. I have no idea why I cant do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

edit: I've removed a lot of completely incorrect babbling on my part and some other unimportant ramblings that have been dealt with later on.

My 2GB problem was in the horribly sloppy interchanging of multiple different types. Mixing of signed and unsigned being the problem. Essentially the 3GB position I was passing to lseek was being interpreted/turned into a position of -1GB and clearly lseek didnt like that. So my bad. Totally stupid.

I am going to change to using posix_fallocate() as p_l suggested. While it does remove one function call i.e. only need posix_fallocate instead of an lseek and then a write, for me that isn't significant, it is the fact that posix_fallocate is doing exactly what I want directly which the lseek method doesn't. So thanks in particular to p_l for suggesting that, and a special thanks to NominalAnimal whose persistence that he knew better indirectly lead me to the realisation that I cant count which in turn led me to accept that posix_fallocate would work and so change to using it.

Regardless of the end method I used. The problem of 2GB was entirely my own crap coding and thanks again to EOF, chux, p_l and Jonathon Leffler who all contributed information and suggestions that lead me to the problem I had created for myself.

I've included a shorter version of this in an answer.

Comment: What file system?  Some e.g. vfat have a hard limit.

Comment: I think `off_t` is only 32 bits long by default.

Comment: I do not think there is a "size parameter to lseek".  There is an"offset" parmeter and I'd expect it to be type `off_t` as in `off_t lseek(int fildes, off_t offset, int whence);`

Comment: Are you creating a 32-bit or 64-bit executable?  If it is 32-bit (`-m32`; it might or might not be the default), what you describe is plausible behaviour unless you use the options (`#define` statements) described in the oldest (only?) answer.  If it is 64-bit (`-m64`, but probably the default), then the behaviour is less plausible.

Comment: @Duck I'm using ext4. There are no apparent limits. As I mentioned, ulimit -a shows no size limits and neither do any of the related config files I've found.

Comment: @EOF 3GB is less than 2^(32-1) so that should make no difference because 3GB is addressable with a 32bit variable. Either way, I've tried re-configuring with and casting to Long long unsigned ints etc and it still fails.

Comment: @Chux poor choice of words in my part. You are correct, there is no size parameter, it's an offset and yes it is of type off_t which on my system is an unsigned long int. Not sure what difference any of  that makes though? unless you are referring to the same sort of thing that EOF is?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I'm compiling specifically for 64 bit i.e. -m64

Comment: @EOF just looked and off_t is actually 64bit. However, it is signed, which makes sense given that lseek returns an off_t (not size_t as I said) and the return value can be negative. So I'll need to look into the whole sequence and make sure that the problem is not something to do with a sign.

Comment: Seeking is useless: it does not change the file size. (You'd have to write to the file after the seek to change file size.) Instead, use [`ftruncate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) or [`posix_fallocate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_fallocate.3.html). The latter allocates disk space for the entire mapping, whereas just truncating it to the desired size does not. If you usually only use a part of the mapping, I recommend truncating only. If the file/mapping will be filled with data, then posix_fallocate() is better, as it avoids fragmentation on disk.

Comment: @Nominal Animal, seeking is not at all useless, if I don't seek to the position that corresponds to the file size I want, then I can't write to that end byte which is what actually creates the file of that size. So seeking is 100% necessary if one is going to use this method. Now using posix_fallocate() seems like it is a much more sensible function to use I agree & will look into it but please, don't say things like this when you clearly haven't tried the method. It DOES work. Unfortunately it only works for files up to 4GB and my problem with the 2GB limit is entirely my fault.

Comment: @gpuMonster: Huh? [I know what I'm talking about](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/data-type-in-c-to-hold-tetrabyte-875026/#post4324888). Seeking alone **is** useless. Seek-then-write is unnecessarily complicated -- and risky; file position handling was only recently fixed in Linux kernel for multiple concurrent writers. (You could use [`pwrite()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html) instead, but even that is a kludge: always allocates that chunk on disk.) The correct (and easy!) solution is always to use `ftruncate()` and/or `posix_fallocate()`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal. Providing an example of a different method in no way proves you 'know what you are talking about'. I find my code with the lseek method MUCH simpler than your example and it is absolutely  much clearer what is being done. The issue of risk is irrelevant since  a) multiple concurrent CPU writers would never be used in my code and specifically are not used in the current function I had an issue with and more importantly b) if its been fixed, how is it risky? To suggest any one method is the CORRECT method, just shows that you are opinionated not correct or even experienced.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Using pwrite() is FAR more complicated than my method. pwrite, ftruncate & posix_fallocate ALL use an off_t which is defined as signed long int on my system. So please explain how I can create a file larger than 4GB with these methods. I can do it with multiple seeks using the lseek method. How would it be done with either pwrite, ftruncate & posix_fallocate if the offset in these functions is limited to 4GB and they cannot be called successively on the same file.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, posix_fallocate would have a limit of 8GB not 4GB since its len + offset and both are signed long ints.

Comment: @NominalAnimal As for your insistance that seeking is useless, I clearly didn't say that I was writing after seeking in my original description but I certainly did in my first reply to you and it is just plain silly to continue the argument that has now changed from seeking is useless to seeking ALONE is useless. We all got what you meant and I stand by my reply to your first comment. I don't want anyone reading this to think incorrectly that the lseek method I'm using doesn't work. It does.

Comment: @gpuMonster: If you use `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` **before** any `#include` lines in all your source files, or use `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` in your compilation command, `off_t` is 64-bit. Also, reread the first two sentences in my first comment, please. As to the `lseek()`/`lseek64()`+`write()` method: it has serious problems (not atomic in kernel, C library quirks, filesystem-specific quirks), and unwanted side effects (the last file chunk is allocated first, sometimes causing file fragmentation and thus slowdown), and is just **wrong** for this! Use the functions **designed** for this!

Comment: @NominalAnimal, those defines are unnecessary, off_t doesn't change and neither do any of the functions you, me or anyone else here has mentioned.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, I already said many replies back that off_t was a signed 64bit int. Unfortunately; as I've stated in my original post and answer and another comment, the problem was that I made some numpty calculation that a signed 64bit int would only allow addressing of 4GB. Now that i'm aware of my mistake, I accept that posix_fallocate works for essentially any file/offset size; as do all the functions including lseek. I stated when p_l first mentioned it that I agree it is 'nicer' solution. All the rest of your stated issues with lseek and write are entirely irrelevant for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

My 2GB problem was in the horribly sloppy interchanging of multiple different types. Mixing of signed and unsigned being the problem. Essentially the 3GB position I was passing to lseek was being interpreted/turned into a position of -1GB and clearly lseek didnt like that. So my bad. Totally stupid crap coding.

Thanks again to EOF, chux, p_l and Jonathon Leffler who all contributed information and suggestions that lead me to the problem I'd created and its  solution.

Thanks again to p_l for suggesting posix_fallocate(), and a special thanks to NominalAnimal whose persistence that he knew better indirectly lead me to the realisation that I cant count which in turn led me to accept that posix_fallocate would work and so change to using it.

@p_l although the solution to my actual problem wasn't in your answer, I'd still up vote your answer that suggested using posix_fallocate but I dont have enough points to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try:

```
//Before any includes:
#define  _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define  _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

If that doesn't work, change `lseek` to `lseek64` like this

```
lseek64(fd, 3221225472, SEEK_SET);
```

A better option than `lseek` might be `posix_fallocate()`:

```
posix_fallocate(fd, 0, 3221225472);
```

before the call to mmap();

I recommend keeping the defines, though :)

Comment: I tried setting those #defines and nothing changed (I have to admit that on a 64bit OS I kind of don't get why they would be necessary). But I haven't tried the lseek64 or posix_fallocate. I'll look into those. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a test program I created (`a2b.c`):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...);

int main(void)
{
    char const filename[] = "big.file";
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to open file %s for reading", filename);
    struct stat sb;
    fstat(fd, &sb);
    uint64_t size = sb.st_size;
    printf("File: %s; size %" PRIu64 "\n", filename, size);
    assert(size > UINT64_C(3) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    off_t offset = UINT64_C(3) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET) < 0)
        err_exit("lseek failed");
    close(fd);
    _Static_assert(sizeof(size_t) > 4, "sizeof(size_t) is too small");
    size = UINT64_C(3) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    void *space = malloc(size);
    if (space == 0)
        err_exit("failed to malloc %zu bytes", size);
    *((char *)space + size - 1) = '\xFF';
    printf("All OK\n");
    return 0;
}

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, ": (%d) %s", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    putc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

When compiled and run on a Mac (Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks, GCC 4.8.2, 16 GiB physical RAM), with command line:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror a2b.c -o a2b
```

and having created `big.file` with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=big.file bs=1048576 count=5000
```

I got the reassuring output:

```
File: big.file; size 5242880000
All OK
```

I had to use `_Static_assert` rather than `static_assert` because the Mac `<assert.h>` header doesn't define `static_assert`.  When I compiled with `-m32`, the static assert triggered.

When I ran it on an Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit VM with 1 GiB virtual physical memory (or is that tautological?), I not very surprisingly got the output:

```
File: big.file; size 5242880000
failed to malloc 3221225472 bytes: (12) Cannot allocate memory
```

I used exactly the same command line to compile the code; it compiled OK on Linux with `static_assert` in place of `_Static_assert`.  The output of `ulimit -a` indicated that the maximum memory size was unlimited, but that means 'no limit smaller than that imposed by the amount of virtual memory on the machine' rather than anything bigger.

Note that my compilations did not explicitly include `-m64` but they were automatically 64-bit compilations.

What do you get?  Can `dd` create the big file?  Does the code compile?  (If you don't have C11 support in your compiler, then you'll need to replace the static assert with a normal 'dynamic' assert, removing the error message.)  Does the code run? What result do you get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example program, `example.c`:

```
/* Not required on 64-bit architectures; recommended anyway. */
#define  _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64

/* Tell the compiler we do need POSIX.1-2001 features. */
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

/* Needed to get MAP_NORESERVE. */
#define  _GNU_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef   FILE_NAME
#define   FILE_NAME   "data.map"
#endif

#ifndef   FILE_SIZE
#define   FILE_SIZE   3221225472UL
#endif

int main(void)
{
    const size_t      size = FILE_SIZE;
    const char *const file = FILE_NAME;

    size_t            page;
    unsigned char    *data;

    int               descriptor;
    int               result;

    /* First, obtain the normal page size. */
    page = (size_t)sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    if (page < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "BUG: sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) returned an invalid value!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Verify the map size is a multiple of page size. */
    if (size % page) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Map size (%lu) is not a multiple of page size (%lu)!\n",
                (unsigned long)size, (unsigned long)page);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Create backing file. */
    do {
        descriptor = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600);
    } while (descriptor == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (descriptor == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create backing file '%s': %s.\n", file, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

#ifdef FILE_ALLOCATE

    /* Allocate disk space for backing file. */
    do {
        result = posix_fallocate(descriptor, (off_t)0, (off_t)size);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot resize and allocate %lu bytes for backing file '%s': %s.\n",
                (unsigned long)size, file, strerror(errno));
        unlink(file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

#else

    /* Backing file is sparse; disk space is not allocated. */
    do {
        result = ftruncate(descriptor, (off_t)size);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot resize backing file '%s' to %lu bytes: %s.\n",
                file, (unsigned long)size, strerror(errno));
        unlink(file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

#endif

    /* Map the file.
     * If MAP_NORESERVE is not used, then the mapping size is limited
     * to the amount of available RAM and swap combined in Linux.
     * MAP_NORESERVE means that no swap is allocated for the mapping;
     * the file itself acts as the backing store. That's why MAP_SHARED
     * is also used. */
    do {
        data = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE,
                    descriptor, (off_t)0);
    } while ((void *)data == MAP_FAILED && errno == EINTR);
    if ((void *)data == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot map file '%s': %s.\n", file, strerror(errno));
        unlink(file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Notify of success. */
    fprintf(stdout, "Mapped %lu bytes of file '%s'.\n", (unsigned long)size, file);
    fflush(stdout);

#if defined(FILE_FILL)
    memset(data, ~0UL, size);
#elif defined(FILE_ZERO)
    memset(data, 0, size);
#elif defined(FILE_MIDDLE)
    data[size/2] = 1; /* One byte in the middle set to one. */
#else

    /*
     * Do something with the mapping, data[0] .. data[size-1]
    */

#endif

    /* Unmap. */
    do {
        result = munmap(data, size);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "munmap(): %s.\n", strerror(errno));

    /* Close the backing file. */
    result = close(descriptor);
    if (result)
        fprintf(stderr, "close(): %s.\n", strerror(errno));

#ifndef FILE_KEEP

    /* Remove the backing file. */
    result = unlink(file);
    if (result)
        fprintf(stderr, "unlink(): %s.\n", strerror(errno));

#endif

    /* We keep the file. */
    fprintf(stdout, "Done.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To compile and run, use e.g.

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 -DFILE_KEEP -DFILE_MIDDLE example.c -o example
./example
```

The above will create a three-gigabyte (1024<sup>3</sup>) sparse file `data.map`, and set the middle byte in it to `1` (`\x01`). All other bytes in the file remain zeroes. You can then run

```
du -h data.map
```

to see how much such a sparse file actually takes on-disk, and

```
hexdump -C data.map
```

if you wish to verify the file contents are what I claim they are.

There are a few compile-time flags (macros) you can use to change how the example program behaves:

- `'-DFILE_NAME="filename"'`

  Use file name `filename` instead of `data.map`. Note that the entire value is defined inside single quotes, so that the shell does not parse the double quotes. (The double quotes are part of the macro value.)
- `'-DFILE_SIZE=(1024*1024*1024)'`

  Use 1024<sup>3</sup> = 1073741824 byte mapping instead of the default 3221225472. If the expression contains special characters the shell would try to evaluate, it is best to enclose it all in single or double quotes.
- `-DFILE_ALLOCATE`

  Allocate actual disk space for the entire mapping. By default, a sparse file is used instead.
- `-DFILE_FILL`

  Fill the entire mapping with `(unsigned char)(~0UL)`, typically 255.
- `-DFILE_ZERO`

  Clear the entire mapping to zero.
- `-DFILE_MIDDLE`

  Set the middle byte in the mapping to 1. All other bytes are unchanged.
- `-DFILE_KEEP`

  Do not delete the data file. This is useful to explore how much data the mapping actually requires on disk; use e.g. `du -h data.map`.

---

There are three key limitations to consider when using memory-mapped files in Linux:

1. File size limits

   Older file systems like FAT (MS-DOS) do not support large files, or sparse files. Sparse files are useful if the dataset is sparse (contains large holes); in that case the unset parts are not stored on disk, and simply read as zeroes.

   Because many filesystems have problems with reads and writes larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 bytes (2147483647 bytes), current Linux kernels internally limit each single operation to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 bytes. The read or write call does not fail, it just returns a *short count*. I am not aware of any filesystem similarly limiting the `llseek()` syscall, but since the C library is responsible for mapping the `lseek()/lseek64()` functions to the proper syscalls, it is quite possible the C library (and not the kernel) limits the functionality. (In the case of the GNU C library and Embedded GNU C library, such syscall mapping is dependent on the compile-time flags. For example, see [`man 7 feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), [`man 2 lseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) and [`man 3 lseek64`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek64.2.html).

   Finally, file position handling is not atomic in most Linux kernels. (Patches are upstream, but I'm not sure which releases contain them.) This means that if more than one thread uses the same descriptor in a way that modifies the file position, it is possible the file position gets completely garbled.
2. Memory limits

   By default, file-backed memory maps are still subject to available memory and swap limits. That is, default `mmap()` behaviour is to assume that at memory pressure, dirty pages are swapped, not flushed to disk. You'll need to use the Linux-specific `MAP_NORESERVE` flag to avoid those limits.
3. Address space limits

   On 32-bit Linux systems, the address space available to an userspace process is typically less than 4 GiB; it is a kernel compile-time option.

   On 64-bit Linux systems, large mappings consume significant amounts of RAM, even if the mapping contents themselves are not yet faulted in. Typically, each single page requires 8 bytes of metadata (*"page table entry"*) in memory, or more, depending on architecture. Using 4096-byte pages, this means a minimum overhead of 0.1953125%, and setting up e.g. a terabyte map requires two gigabytes of RAM just in page table structures!

   Many 64-bit systems in Linux support *huge pages* to avoid that overhead. In most cases, huge pages are of limited use due to the [configuration and tweaking and limitations](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt). Kernels also may have limitations on what a process can do with a huge page mapping; a robust application would need thorough fallbacks to normal page mappings.

The kernel may impose stricter limits than resource availability to user-space processes. Run `bash -c 'ulimit -a'` to see the currently-imposed limits. (Details are available in the [ulimit](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-ulimit) section in `man bash-builtins`.)

Comment: Wow, that is an incredible amount of effort to go to to prove a point. Cudos. Unfortunately most of that is entirely irrelevant. HOWEVER. Compiling and running your code did make me realise that I've been staying up too late. What I wish you had said from the beginning was "Hey dude, your calcs are wrong, off_t can address 2^(64-1) which is about as large a file as anyone could ever want as opposed to the crazy 4GB limit you were babbling about"

Comment: @gpuMonster: No, I'm not proving a point. A lot of high-performance computing data backends are programmed using stupid methods, adding caching layers on top of caching layers, requiring exponential amounts of hardware to achieve necessary data rates (see Cern/LHC backends, for example). My worry, and reason for my effort, is those who read these threads afterwards. The *"experts"* here rarely admit their errors; everybody just "moves on". That might otherwise be fine, but fact is, these threads remain here, easily Googled, leading future programmers astray.

Comment: @gpuMonster: Personally, it just didn't occur to me to consider your problem a simple typo or miscalculation. In fact, if you find a way to express simply the *way* your miscalculation happened, and added that to your question, I think it would help others encountering similar problems more than anything else offered in this thread... After all, we learn most from mistakes. I just want to make sure that errors and poor choices are clearly marked as such, so that those who build upon us will become better than we are.

Comment: @gpuMonster: Memory mapping techniques on 64-bit architectures is an excellent example of a very, very sharply honed edge: you can achieve a lot, but there are a lot of downsides (like `SIGSEGV` signals instead of `ENOSPC` errors when running out of space, and the amount of tunables (`msync()`, `madvise()`, etc.) available to get the best performance). A properly tuned, but simple memory-mapping dataset server can blow any userspace-caching systems away, using the same resources. But that, I fear, is another flamefest... :)

Comment: I have zero interest in high performance CPU code. What I write to run on the CPU does the bare necessities to get data to and from the GPU. Basic file operations of finding, opening, creating, reading and writing. The GPU stuff I work on can take a cluster of top end GPU's days to compute so the difference between how many seconds or minutes the CPU code takes, is just not  important. tunables; dont need them, one signal vs another, makes no difference. The CPU stuff is single threaded, has hundreds of terrabytes of disk and hundreds of gigabytes of ram, guaranteed.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: When I look at `man mmap` on Linux, it doesn't say `EINTR` can be raised. What gives?

Comment: @EOF: LOL, I guess that's one of those risky things about using a ... function. I guess I'll have to put that on the list of incorrect usage of a function. We just cannot work without not knowing about EINTR. That will never do. Definitely a kludge. Should we file a bug report? :(

Comment: @EOF: `man 7 signal` does not list `mmap` in the async-signal-safe functions, either; it is a corner case. There have been quite a few issues wrt. mmap() and EINTR, see [eCryptFS](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/3/5/214) for example. You see, in Linux kernel the `mmap()` function is filesystem-specific (although most just end up calling the generic version). I am simply playing safe, here.

Comment: @gpuMonster: Stop being butthurt, and look at the facts instead. Only the questions and answers matter. For example: I used to use `do { rc = close(fd); } while (rc == -1 && errno == EINTR);` loop for the same reasons as for `mmap()`, until it was *recently* pointed to me `close()` was a special case -- even if it returns an error, in Linux the *file descriptor is always closed*. So, in Linux, you never loop on `close()`; otherwise you risk closing unrelated file descriptors.

Comment: That's yet another lovely story. And I for one am super impressed with your clearly infinite knowledge and experience with, well just about everything. But it seemed to be suggesting that you learned you were doing something you shouldn't because it was dangerious. But your link to cryptFS suggested: ">Should we be suppressing the message when we see EINTR? >Yes. In fact, eCryptfs shouldn't print a KERN_ERR message at all in this situation. KERN_DEBUG at most". So what is your point? You've learned you're doing something pointless? How does that relate to your comment that it's playing it safe

Comment: @NominalAnimal, if your general approach is to try an bamboozle people with intricate details, and pages of dot points of irrelevant fun facts, then I think you need a new one. You sure lost me and your general attitude would have all by itself btw. Telling people that they are doing things the 'wrong way' is just a bit childish  don't you think? and throwing more and more examples on the fire to cover your words, just doesnt work when they dont actually back up your argument. In this case, nothing in that link suggested you should play it safe, rather that the signal can safely be ignored.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: reading the section `async-signal-safe functions` in `man 7 signal`, it purports to be about which functions are safe to call in signal handlers. Nothing suggests ordinary code has to worry about this, as long as the signal handlers are programmed competently. Should I ask a new question about this?

Comment: @EOF: Async-signal-safe function list, in my experience, is a good indicator of how much there has been thought wrt. signal interaction and the function. (After all, `EINTR` occurs when instead of performing a syscall, the kernel delivers a signal to userspace. A Linux fs can implement `mmap()` such that it may return `EINTR` (I thought eCryptFS did), and because it is not an async-signal-safe function, I don't think C lib devs bother to make sure it is not returned to userspace. (`ERESTARTSYS` issues are similar, see e.g. [RH #455729](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=455729).)

Comment: @gpuMonster: No, I'm just sick of "devs" like you who generate crappy code, and always respond with "but it works on my machine!" indignantly -- pointing out issues in your code is a personal slight to you. I've had to try and fix such crap code enough already. Writing code that falls apart at the next library or hardware upgrade is a disgrace, and such "devs" should never be hired in the first place: waste of resources. You don't care, you move on before anyone notices the inherent underlying problems in your output. You blame your ex-coworkers for any issues. I care, and I'm still learning.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, where on earth do you come up with this stuff? You've not seen a single line of my 'crappy code'. YOU didn't point out anything, p_l suggested using posix_fallocate and far from being a slight on me, I said from the start that I thought it looked like a better solution, said thanks to p_l and then wrote that I am now using it. As for moving on before anyone notices a problem, that's just baffling. This very thread shows I've done exactly the opposite! I ask for and received help from people on these forums and FIXED the code immediately. When did I blame anyone but myself?

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Suggesting I'm writing code that would fall apart is nothing more than a childish comment from someone lashing out in anger. You don't even know what I am doing or developing. For your information, at THIS stage of development, we are creating GPU code to solve scientific solutions for a very specific hardware platform. We need to prove first that the GPU code actually solves the problems it needs to solve and does so fast enough to be useable. So yes, I in that respect I don't care about the CPU code. We're not developing new ways to open/create, read & write files on CPU's.

Comment: @gpuMonster: No, there is no anger. I don't know *you*, I'm solely basing my opinion on what you have written here. For example, I have heard the *"I don't need to know about X"/"I don't care about X"* comment quite a few times, always by a *"[I have a hammer](http://www.yacoset.com/Home/signs-that-you-re-a-bad-programmer)"* -class "programmer". Furthermore, you have amply demonstrated you don't understand the difference between using `ftruncate()` and `posix_fallocate()` on a newly created file, nor the unwanted side effects when relying on `lseek()`+`write()`.

Comment: @gpuMonster: If you ever work with e.g. huge sparse matrices, you'll hopefully try and see the kind of effect using `ftruncate()` has over `posix_fallocate()` in wall-clock running time (not to mention disk space used). Perhaps then you'll revisit my comments, and understand my reasoning. However, I suspect you won't -- considering your attitude thus far. (As to "childish", I take it as a compliment. At least children keep their minds open.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal, yet again you presume to somehow magically know what we are doing. These files are ALWAYS filled with data. Why on earth would I want it to be sparse? Why would I care? They will contain a new version of a 3D CT/MRI/SEM image that has had various filters applied to it. Seriously dude. What are you smoking? And I love the way you ignored absolutely everything else that has been said and somehow introduced the idea that I'm not open minded because I chose to use posix_fallocate vs ftruncate. Also, explain to me why on earth you included posix_fallocate in your code if its no good

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Exactly WHERE did I describe the differences between using lseek and write, ftruncate, and posix_fallocate? You just make this stuff up and think people will swallow it? Serious dude. Where is this? You mean because I was saying I thought it was not going to work because I made a mistake in calculating the addressable range of off_t? Or was it the part where I said I thought posix_fallocate was a nicer solution? Or was it the part where I commented on your pointless checking of an error code?

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I don't need to know or hear about X when X has no baring on whether we can prove we can numerically solve a scientific theory is the CORRECT approach to take. Gazzilions of dollars are being spent on proving we can solve things that have never been solved before & that we can implement GPU acceleration techniques that allow certain other things to be solved sometimes more than 100x faster than anything else out there we know of, and you want to lecture people on the DANGERS of not checking mmap for a (EINTR) return code that the documentation says cant be returned? LOL.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Oh did I ever mention that we good scientific people did in fact test the difference between ftruncate & fallocate. What do you think the performance difference was. This was testing in isolation and as part of one of our filter routines on a 16GB file? 0.093s. That is the average difference in how much longer fallocate takes over ftruncate. Given such a small diff & the fact that truncate is clearly intended to TRUNCATE a file (although it can extend) & fallocate is designed to create or extend a file. We went with the function that does what we actually want to do. Allocate.

Comment: @nominalAnimal: Do I need to remind you that the files being create are all 100% dense and always will be. So there certainly isnt any disk space need to create some sparse file first.