# cannot write(2) file larger than 2GB (up to 2TB)

Tags: c, linux, writefile

I have a program written by C. It computes something and writes the output into a file. My problem is that it does not write more than 2GB. Let me put a simplified code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main() {
    size_t size = 3221225472LL;
    char *map = malloc(size);
    size_t allocated = malloc_usable_size(map);
    int fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0644);
    ssize_t written = write(fd, map, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Although the output file "myfile" is being created, the size is always 2GB (2147479552 Bytes) for whatever size greater than 2GB I requested. The `malloc()` successfully allocated memory of the requested size (in this case, "allocated" is 3GB). The `errno` after `write()` is 0.

The environment is the following

- OS:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 x86_64
- Physical memory size: 32GB
- File system: ext4

Compilation:

```
gcc code.c -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
```

What could be the reason for this?

**Addition:**

After getting two responses, I added retry code as following:

```
int main() {
    size_t size = 3221225472LL;
    char *map = malloc(size);
    size_t allocated = malloc_usable_size(map);
    int fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0644);
    ssize_t written = write(fd, map, size);
    while (written < size) {
        written += write(fd, &map[written], size-written);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `written`?

Comment: Although it seems to be unrelated to this in the end, I think that it could have been valuable to have the file system type as well.

Comment: The terabyte size should go into the question, so please **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it. What is your actual application really doing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (emphasis mine)

> On Linux, `write()` (and similar system calls) will transfer ***at most 0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes***, returning the number of bytes actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.)

Comment: thank you! I see it now .. After your response, I put some retry write() code on the left over buffer. It is working.

Comment: On MacOS, writing more than `0x7fffffff` bytes will fail with errno 22, so simply adding a retry code is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

Some file systems have strong limitations on file size, notably FAT32. And both [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) and resource limits (see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_FSIZE`) are limiting the file size (and of course the available space on the file system itself).

BTW, your `written` is very probably (after your call to [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)...) only 2<sup>31</sup>. You should check it.

And [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) documents:

> On Linux, write() (and similar system calls) will transfer at most
>          0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes
>          actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit
>          systems.)

Of course, a given call to [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) should never be expected to have written all the required bytes (and this is true on all POSIX systems, and was true on Unix systems of the 1980s). For example, a `write` to some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) surely won't be able to write that many bytes.

BTW, a huge single call to [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is probably (or at least could well be) less efficient than several of them with a smaller buffer. The optimal buffer size is implementation specific (and related also to the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) and to the hardware) but might be several dozen of kilobytes, or at most a megabyte.

You may prefer to use `<stdio.h>` *buffered* [fwrite(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html) but you should check the returned count.

At last, you might consider using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) in your case. See also [msync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html)

Notice that for large files, the real bottleneck is the hardware (the disk itself). So it does not matter much to use buffered `fwrite` for performance.

<sup>(you mention a terabyte file in a comment)</sup>

BTW, for large terabyte datasets, using some higher-level approach (notably a database, perhaps with [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), or an indexed file à la [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)) could actually be more efficient, because you are then able to write only a *portion* of the data (or because the [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) runs on a remote database server, e.g. using [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/) or [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/)). YMMV. But the hardware bandwidth is less than a Gbyte/sec so writing a terabyte might take a few hours. And even with a huge swap size you won't be able to `malloc` a terabyte without [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) on a 32 Gbyte machine.

You might also use cleverly [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) to slightly improve performance (but not much: for terabyte files the bottleneck is the hardware)

Comment: Thank you! I will try fwrite(3) and mmap(2) and see which works best. The total amount to write() from my program is a few TB. So I guess it's better to use efficient way.

Comment: No, for a TB file the way you write to it is not very important. The bottleneck is the hardware.

Comment: BTW, that terabyte size should go into your question